# How can i find out how to get the right pk?

Tags: python, django, percentage

I'm new to programming and I'm practicing on making a poll app. But im stuck trying to get the percentage of each choice voted, like so:

Models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Views.py:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'posts/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
        published in the future).
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'posts/detail.html'


class ResultsView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'posts/results.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultsView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        q = Question.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        total = q.choice_set.aggregate(Sum('votes'))

        percentage = q.choice_set.get(
            pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).votes / total['votes__sum']

        context['total'] = total['votes__sum']
        context['percentage'] = percentage

        return context


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'posts/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:results', args=(question.id,)))
P
```

The Problem is that, as I try to get the percentage, im getting the wronk pk, and dont know how to make it right. In this case, im trying to get each choice votes and divide by the total votes, the total works just fine, but cant get the value for each choice.

Any tips? is there a easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `annotate` to calculate the percentage for each `Choice`. The number of votes is an integer so you'll need to `Cast` it to a float so that you use float division rather than integer division

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import Sum, FloatField

question = Question.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
total_votes = question.choice_set.aggregate(Sum('votes'))['votes__sum']
choices = question.choice_set.annotate(
    percentage=Cast('votes', output_field=FloatField()) / total_votes
)

for choice in choices:
    print(choice, choice.percentage)
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.